# Why can't I extrude a Nurbs curve along a nurbs path

Tags: extrude

What is the protocol for extruding objects along paths.
I cannot find any user-friendly assistance in the manual.
I am not used to the CAD geometry approach as I have more experience with the older Finite Element packages, where the geometry was constructed then meshed. Extrusion, mirroring etc were intuitive.

Also, I constructed a nurbs path in the shape of a wheel section, and constructed what I thought was going to be a separate nurbs circle, perpendicular to the plane of the wheel section, running through one end of the section path.
When I tried to perform the extrusion, using E, and transform rotate, there appeared to be no control over the transformation re axis.
When I selected the nurbs circle, I found that it had merged with the wheel section.
1) How do I separate them, and
2) Can I perform the extrusion using this method?

I am using v2.76  on a fairly quick XP SP3 32bit 3.3GHz Pentium 2 core and a GeForce 6200, with adequate ram and hdd.

Answer (score 0):

By saying extrude along a path, are you referring to 'Skinning'? If so, they have to be separate objects, then you use one as a 'Bevel' object to skin(bevel) the path. If you could post a screen shot and clarify this, it would help.

Comment: I think I will have to Spin the profile curve  to create the  wheelrim - this effectively a rotational extrusion  - haven't tried it yet - I'm still struggling with sidebar issues.I also struggle with the terminology eg bevel seems to mean more than creating a bevel edge! I'll look in again tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean about the terminology, from mesh to curve it's not consistent.Don't forget about using an 'Array' modifier with an 'Empty' as the 'Object Offset' to spin the shape, works well in cases like this.